# Can a person survive without platlets in the bloodstream?

Tags: human-anatomy, hematology

Can a person survive without platlets or thrombocytes in the bloodstream, if I guarentee that the person is isolated and won't injure?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Platelets not only function to prevent overflow of blood from the body by making clots. A considerable increase or decrease in the platelets in the blood can cause **thrombocytopenia**. Thrombocytopenia is a disease with nose bleeding, red spots on skin, vomits of blood, pink-coloured urine and headaches as common symptoms. Also, even if an isolated environment is provided you cannot prevent slight injuries like acidity and dust particles in the air.